# $\mathbb C$-isomorphism between two $\mathbb C$-schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

Consider a field automorphism $\sigma\in\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb C)$, and moreover consider the $\mathbb C$-scheme $p:\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}\longrightarrow\textrm{Spec}\,{\mathbb C}$ where $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}=\textrm{Proj}\mathbb C[T_0,T_1]$.

We can define the $\mathbb C$-scheme $$\textrm{Spec}(\sigma)\circ p:\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}\longrightarrow\textrm{Spec}\,{\mathbb C}$$
that we indicate with ${\left(\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}\right)}^\sigma$. Now I have to find an isomorphism of $\mathbb C$-schemes (not only an isomorphism of schemes) between ${\left(\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}\right)}^\sigma$ and $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$. Do you have  any idea about the construction of this isomorphism?

---

**attempt of solution**: Consider the induced isomorphism  of $\mathbb C$-algebras 
$$\overline\sigma:\mathbb C[T_0,T_1]\longrightarrow\mathbb C[T_0,T_1]$$
where the rightmost $C[T_0,T_1]$ has the following structure of $\mathbb C$-algebra:
$$\mathbb C\owns a\mapsto\sigma(a)\in \mathbb C[T_0,T_1]$$

In this way is well defined the map 
$$\textrm{Proj}(\overline\sigma):{\left(\mathbb P^1_\mathbb C\right)}^\sigma \longrightarrow\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$$

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct (and almost complete).

More abstractly, notice that there is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-schemes ${\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}}^\sigma = \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}} \otimes_{\mathbb{C},\sigma^{-1}} \mathbb{C}$, where on the right we tensor with $\sigma^{-1} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, and the $\mathbb{C}$-scheme structure is induced by the right tensor factor. (Of course, actually we take the fiber product with $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}))$ etc.).

Now in general, if $f : A \to B$ is any homomorphism of commutative rings, then there is an isomorphism of $B$-schemes $\mathbb{P}^1_A \otimes_{A,f} B = \mathbb{P}^1_B$. Applying this to $\sigma^{-1} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, we get $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}} \otimes_{\mathbb{C},\sigma^{-1}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ where now the $\mathbb{C}$-scheme structure is the usual one.

Comment: Using your approach, there is a way to show that the isomorphism is precisely $\textrm{Proj}(\overline\sigma)$?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: You have proved that there exists an isomorphism. In my solution I claim explicitly that the isomorphism is $\textrm{Proj}(\overline\sigma)$. I like your general approach, but I don't understand how to deduce that the isomorphism is $\textrm{Proj}(\overline\sigma)$.

Comment: My proof is constructive. It produces an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes you are right. I've thinked about it.